# How can I rewrite this MATLAB code using vectorization?

Tags: matlab, if-statement

How can I write this code faster in MATLAB? Maybe using vectorizations. Basically I do not know how to vectorize with `if`. In the following, if an element of the array `u` is 0, then the while loop happens with an update. If the element is non zero then  `benefit(c,t,w) = B(c,tprime,w)/u(c,tprime,w);` and `i(c,t,w) = tprime ;` happens.

```
county_size=3 ; time_size = 3; scenario_size = 3;
for c=1:county_size
    for w=1:scenario_size
        for t=tt:time_size
            l = u(c,t,w) ;
            tprime = t ;
            while (l==0)
                if tprime > time_size-1
                    tprime = time_size + 1 ;
                    B(c,time_size + 1,w) = 0 ;
                    u(c,time_size + 1,w) = 1 ;
                    break
                end
                l = u(c,tprime+1,w) ;
                tprime = tprime + 1 ;
            end
            benefit(c,t,w) = B(c,tprime,w)/u(c,tprime,w) ;
            i(c,t,w)       = tprime ;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please provide an executable code.

Comment: A description of what you're trying to do would also help.

Comment: @beaker I do not wish to have 3 for loops.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. A description of what your code currently does would help. The inputs, the calculations it performs on the inputs, and the desired outputs.

Comment: @SardarUsama edited a bit now. You can use any random values - I just need a way to perhaps avoid the loops

Comment: Instead of asking about an attempted solution, it will be better if you ask about your actual problem.

Comment: @beaker edited a bit now.

Comment: @SardarUsama unfortunately i need specifically this solution methodology, not a new way to achieve the same. So I just need a way to avoid the loops if possible

Comment: Your two sentences in above comment contradict each other.

Comment: Also, please provide code that can be run as is. That is, define `tt` and other required variables

Answer (score 1):

I will understand this request for vectorization as a more general, how to improve the performance, looking at this part:

```
 tprime = t ;
 while (l==0)
 if tprime > time_size-1
   tprime = time_size + 1 ;
   B(c,time_size + 1,w) = 0 ;
   u(c,time_size + 1,w) = 1 ;
   break
 end
 l = u(c,tprime+1,w) ;
 tprime = tprime + 1 ;
 end
```

The only purpose of the `while` is to find the first nonzero element in `u(c,t:end-1,w)`. There is a function for this purpose, `find` with the third argument set to `first`.

Comment: You have the correct aim of what I wish to do. I can do this without the while loop now as you said with find. How can I do this in a vectorizable way without the outside for loop around c and w?